# Python - How to update a value in a json file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I hate json files. They are unwieldy and hard to handle :( Please tell me why the following doesn't work:

```
with open('data.json', 'r+') as file_object:
        data = json.load(file_object)[user_1]['balance']
        am_nt = 5
        data += int(am_nt['amount'])
        print(data)
        file_object[user_1]['balance'] = data
```

Through trial and error (and many print statements), I have discovered that it opens the file, goes to the correct place, and then actually adds the am_nt, but I can't make the original json file update. Please help me :( :( . I get:

```
2000
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

json is fun to work with as it is similar to python data structures.

The error is: `object is not subscriptable` 
This error is for this line:
    `file_object[user_1]['balance'] = data`

`file_object` is not  json/dictionary data that can be updated like above. Hence the error.

Try to read the json data:
    `data=json.load(file_object)`

Then manipulate the data as python dictionary. And save the file.